# using triggers to store interaction history, but seeing null values

Tags: vega

I was looking at [triggers](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/triggers/) to store the sequence of `brush` signals. [Here is the link to the editor with the full spec](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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-WKVpbI1HB8QoyFMh0yABewTYaDPcElICQUfD8tA-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-wk-DADUejyJzbjizAksAIwy3LFY5Acei09mj3If2ICzY+BrKzOy0Dei4UyGtCpM1tSw7YTi3Q6doO4-jIaTi493OzA+spQO0ao5ddUhTbGh21921OwtMCuyDF0ezdZVPQbqXG-LJwW8Fq2R6A9vfbdsdEwnIfgyjUPo7DODw0jEOownx2kDjMg83ir16AAtHoUYh+nQddiOorbLCRNLGq5oRwyhcsxN7YTF+ce1ldeMpyN4i+3Hj16AA-P44hRJg90AORRgA8v9cQn24fs76gehW08EorgBL4zVl0aXwdAMlBhyY0FTCAOceIeJ1h5CpTcVx1LOQoviXmxJB5+W-tEX+Y5ZIgEnOIacs5fDzmmJUJcK4zoQO9IWS424LIuX3O5Fex5USoDvJea8t5RL3hXE+d+YEPzWhAN+X8ylYL2TKigvKyEJIymmiCccckdAoD5IREIYQaCkDQOYKacAyxKUgRQmBmlcI6VAO3AyPkO6iLQSAcirl9I2VMQhcxcRYGuQPB5Py3lvRv3sVffKPoVrBl6hFXxA0QxBDiglIMht-7oB0GETKZI+HLwKgY-CJUZzelsh1AajU4BNFIpFYKhD-FpECWHEAABiR0lSV4BPPj0KAdAMn5KqpQaoDFjHenKqzSanYElEylivKM7iukLx6X7aYatEqRJkcAqkMEQABAyKEcIkJ1GTE0QRbSKTFEmkaUE3OwYmqZIKW1JiXomloBVkUvqRy8QpB0PNFEdheJtzXrzDprZulLz6cuSZqUokzNiQoxZyjVGoFWQiJJmzirbPSf1fZDQclWjhZCQpHpTksXOagS5YUSmdUsTQe5zgnltNefhTp892ZzTjuM96ETkrJSAA). The relevant code I added is here:

```
    {
      "name": "selected",
      "on": [
        {"trigger": "detailDomain", "insert": "detailDomain"}
      ]
    }
```

However, when I look at the data viewer (in the editor), I don't see any values (I think `null` values are being inserted). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the Vega editor had a bug. The events are actually captured!